# Is the word "visibility" misused?

Tags: word-usage

I often hear or read the word "visibility" used in a way that sounds wrong to me. If something is visible it is able to be seen. Therefore visibility is the ability to be seen.

When speaking of a car someone might say, "larger windows increase visibility." No, painting your car fluorescent orange will increase visibility. Larger windows give you a better field of view but they don't increase the car's ability to be seen by others.

Is this usage incorrect our am I missing something? Has the word now taken on a new meaning through misuse?

Comment: Large windows increase the visibility of the things outside the car.

Answer (score 3):

***[Visibility](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/visibility)*** can be applied to different contexts, both usagse you mention are correct:

> - Use the noun visibility to describe how well you can see something, like the great visibility from the top of a mountain on a clear day.
> - In addition to meaning "how well you can see," visibility can also mean "how well others can see something." So, the reflective stripes on your running pants give you visibility in the dark because they help other people see you.
> - Another kind of visibility is being in the public eye, like an actor whose visibility helps him land roles in movies and promote the causes he cares about, like literacy or helping endangered animals.

(Vocabulary.com)

[Visibility](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=visibility%20), (from Etymonline):

> - c. 1400, "condition of being visible," from Late Latin visibilitatem (nominative visibilitas) "condition of being seen; conspicuousness," from visibilis (see visible). ***Meaning "range of vision under given conditions" is from 1914. Sense of "prominence, fame, public attention" is recorded from 1958.***

Answer (score 0):

Both senses are recognised by the OED. The etymology is from "late Latin".

The original and principal meaning relates to the condition, state and fact of being visible. There are examples from 1581.

> *1581   W. Fulke in A. Nowell et al. True Rep. Disput. E. Campion (1584) ii. sig. H ij b,   What visibilitie could there be in those
>   daies.., when there was no face at all of an outward Church?*

The alternative meaning seems from the examples given in the OED to have become current during naval warfare during the first world war. It is OED sense 1c.

> *spec. The possibility of (a vessel, etc.) being seen under the conditions of distance, light, atmosphere, etc., existing at a
>   particular time; hence conversely, the possibility of seeing, or the
>   range of vision, under such conditions.Cf. Harbord Gloss. Navig.
>   (1863), s.v. Weather notation.*
>
> 1914   tr. Baudry's Naval Battle 265   The radius of visibility must
>   fix the maximum time allowable for final preparations.
>
> 1916   J. Jellicoe Disp. 24 June in Battle of Jutland 62   The
>   visibility early on 1st June (three to four miles) was less than on
>   31st May.